# How to assign bulk parameter to Django object values list?

Tags: python, django, django-views

How to assign bulk parameters to the Django object values list?

1. Bulk parameter assignment

```
strlist = ["a","b","c"]
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list(strlist)
```

**Result**:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

2. Manual assignment

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list("a","b","c")
```

**Result** is ok

How to assign a bulk parameter assignment?

Comment: Use `*` to unpack your list as positional args - `.values_list(*strlist)`

Comment: Why do you need `.values_list`? Usually it is not a good idea to work with `.values`/`.values_list`, since it results in "simple types", not model objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:
Try:

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list(*strlist)
```

Explaination:
The problem is that the function requires you to enter unpacked values. There is a difference between a `list` and `*list`. `*list` represents the unpacking of individual values inside a list and then entering them.
So,

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list(strlist)
```

Is interpreted as

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list(["a", "b", "c"])
```

But

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list(*strlist)
```

Is interpreted as

```
model1. objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list("a", "b", "c")
```

Example 1:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
print(a)
print(*a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
1 2 3 4
```

So, while `a` represents the list `a` but in list form, `*a` represents the list `a` as its individual elements. Hence even if you try to index `*a`, it shows an error.
On the other hand `**dict1` refers to the scenario where the dictionary `dict1` has the arguments as key-value pairs. Eg.:

```
def b(hel, lo, wo, rl):
    print(hel, lo, wo, rl)

a = [1,2,3,4]
d = {'hel':1, 'lo':2, 'rl':3, 'wo':4}
b(*a)
b(**d)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
```